# Is it possible to reopen running Sublime command console without hitting ctrl+B again (to prevent a new start)?

Tags: console, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I run a code in sublime command console but accidentally pressed `ctrl+f` to find some text in the code. So the command console is replaced by search box. How can I make command console appear again without hitting ctrl+B as it will start a new code running? The code is run so far, I just want to continue it and need to see the progress is printed (I have the print line in the code) in console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just select *Tools > Build Results > Show Build Results*. You can also add a keybinding for it. E.g.

```js
{
    "keys": ["alt+b"],
    "command": "show_panel",
    "args": { "panel": "output.exec" },
},
```

Comment: An additional (non-obvious) method is to select `Build Results` from the panel switcher menu, which is the icon at the extreme left of the status bar. I think the key bind is the superior method, though.